# Como redirecionar para uma url externa utilizando React useEffect?

Tags: react, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Estou tentando redirecionar para uma url externa ,utilizando a função vaiparala passando um parametro
que eu pego a partir do click, o caminho chega na funçao corretamente mas o redirecionamento não
é feito , o que eu posso estar fazendo de errado ?

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const vaiparala = (caminho) => {
      console.log(caminho);
      caminho === 'Linkedin' ? (
        <Link to={"https://www.linkedin.com/feed/"} />
      ) : (
        history.push(`/${caminho}`)
      );
    };
    const handleClick = (e) => {
      const items = document.getElementsByClassName('context-menu-item');

      if (items && items.length > 0) {
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          if (items[i].contains(e.target)) {
            vaiparala(rotasClick[i]);
            count++;
          }
        }
        if (count === 0) {
          setActive(false);
        }
      } else {
        setActive(false);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode redirecionar para uma URL externa usando `react-router` - `Link`, `Redirect` ou `history.push`.

Mas você pode fazer isso: `window.location.href = 'https://www.linkedin.com/feed/'` ou `window.location.replace('https://www.linkedin.com/feed/')`.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const vaiparala = (caminho) => {
      console.log(caminho);
      caminho === 'Linkedin' ? (
        window.location.href = 'https://www.linkedin.com/feed/'
        // ou
        window.location.replace('https://www.linkedin.com/feed/')
      ) : (
        history.push(`/${caminho}`)
      );
    };
    // ...
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente , muito obrigado !